# Is it possible to create a generic SPI / QSPI flash memory driver that works with any QSPI device?

Tags: spi

Most/all SPI/QSPI memories support the same basic command set. E.g., 0x02 is page program, 0x03 is read, 0x06 is write enable and so on.
However, erase units, sector protection, or just checking the success/failure of a previous program/erase operation seem to be different from device to device.

An example: in the status register (command RDSR, 0x05), some bits seem to be standard, but bit 6 can be Programming Error, Quad Mode Enable or Sector Protect in different devices. To read the prog error flag some devices use the 0x2b command, that's not supported or doing something else on other devices.

Is it possible to figure out how is the device working from the JEDEC info? Is it possible to divide flash devices into a few groups that work in similar ways?
The idea is creating a "generic" driver that works with most standard devices, instead of creating a separate driver for each flash part.

Comment: Isn’t that done already?

Comment: Not really. Basic operations are standardized, but checking whether the operation was a success or failure is vendor-specific. Different register has to be read with different commands and the bits are in different position for each vendor. Furthermore, Spansion/Infineon devices "lock up" after any error, the cannot be read, either. A status register clear or reset instruction has to be issued that are not supported by other devices. They're quite different.